# I need to implement a Security lock in my application like applock

Tags: java, android, security

I need to show a security prompt to the user whenever he lands on a certain page, also when he comes back via home key or recents key, but the fragements and activity life cycle callbacks are varied on different OEM's,
i tried using activity stack to monitor topactivity, but it returns only my application package, What else can be done.

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks = manager.getRunningTasks(1);
            String mPackageName="";
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20){
                mPackageName= manager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
            }
            else{
                mPackageName = manager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
            }
            if (runningTasks != null && runningTasks.size() > 0) {
                ComponentName topActivity = runningTasks.get(0).topActivity;
                if (!mPackageName.equals(getPackageName())) {
                    isTopActivityFromApp = false;
                } else {
                    if (mPackageName.equals(getPackageName()) && topActivity.getClassName().equals(PaySendActivity.class.getName()) && !isTopActivityFromApp) {
                        // Other Application is opened
                        isTopActivityFromApp = true;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            if (WalletSharedPrefs.INSTANCE.isPatternLockEnabled(getApplicationContext())) {
                                showprompt();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I think you have to build a launcher application like Nova Launcher or like Go Launcher and so on. I think it's the only way to intercept other application's work

Comment: No, i dont need to develop a launcher app, all i need to do is to show a secure lock on one of my activity whenever the user lands,either from recents or home.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 3rd party libraries and you could find what you are searching for
[here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/56)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage top activity in your app the best way to do it is to listen for your onResume/onPause methods with [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)
but if you want to manage the top activity of other app, you can only track their package names not the class name of the top activity and the best way to do it is to use [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html).